# Making HttpWebRequest calls in parallel with Threading.Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest, task

Is there some issue with making HttpWebRequest calls in parallel with Threading.Tasks in C# (I am using mono to compile in Ubuntu)?
When I make 25 GET requests to Google in sync it takes about 2-3 seconds total. When I make async calls it takes over 13 seconds. My code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Google
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Stopwatch timer1 = new Stopwatch();
        timer1.Start();

        for(int i=1; i<=25; i++){
            googleit();
        }
        timer1.Stop();
        TimeSpan timeTaken1 = timer1.Elapsed;


        Stopwatch timer2 = new Stopwatch();
        timer2.Start();

        int TaskCount = 25;
        var tasks = new Task[TaskCount];
        for (var index = 0; index < TaskCount; index++)
        {
            tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(googleit);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        timer2.Stop();
        TimeSpan timeTaken2 = timer2.Elapsed;


        Console.WriteLine("Sync time: ");
        Console.WriteLine(timeTaken1);
        Console.WriteLine("async time: ");
        Console.WriteLine(timeTaken2);
    }
    private static void googleit(){
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();

        timer.Stop();
        TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(timeTaken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionsLimit = 500;` at the very beginning, before anything.

Comment: And most certainly do not test performance with that `Console.WriteLine` in there. `googleit()` should be 4 lines long.

Comment: The "async" code is actually not making asynchronous requests. It's spinning up tasks that make synchronous requests. Change it to use `request.GetRequestAsync()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Comment: Agreed that the code is the wrong way to do asynchronous requests. Also, you should extend your timing code so that you can see how long _each_ request takes, in both the synchronous and asynchronous scenarios. It's possible that most of the requests complete quickly, but that at some point, one (or a few) takes a long time. Maybe not, but you should be sure if you want to debug this.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am unable to reproduce your described problem. The synchronous version on my PC takes 5.7 seconds, while the asynchronous version takes 1.5 seconds. Windows 8.1. You should still fix the code so that it does true asynchronous I/O instead of concurrent synchronous operations, but it seems that there is not actually anything about the code itself that causes the delay. Maybe your ISP is just throttling you, or maybe Google did because you were testing the code during peak periods (it's late at night where I am).

Comment: @Yorye Adding the line about the ServicePointManager did not help.

Comment: You're printing in the loop that is being timed for performance. This invalidates your results, as `Console.WriteLine` is a very expensive operation.

Comment: @anthony What I hope to get get out of this exercise is to be able make async calls to some other code that synchronously makes `HttpWebRequests`'s. This there an alternative to `Task.Factory.StartNew()` that will allow me to make asynchronous calls of synchronous code featuring `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`?

Comment: @Yorye removing the Console calls in googleit still gives me times:
Sync time: 
00:00:02.5445574
async time: 
00:00:16.3181367

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need:

```
public static void SendAsync()
{
    int TaskCount = 8;
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, TaskCount).Select(p => googleit());
    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
}
private static async Task googleit()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    response.Close();
}
```

It will send all requests asynchronously, and wait (block).

In your code, you were just creating a task for each request. So if you have 2 cores, for example, and TPL decides to split all the tasks between two threads, you'll have two threads synchronously sending the requests. On one core, you'd have completely synchronous execution. 
In the above code, you have **one** thread sending **all** the requests asynchronously, that is, it posts a requests and moves on to send the next one, without waiting for the previous to return. After all requests had been sent, it blocks the thread until the continuations - in your case 'response.Close()' - are done.